# Import Dump to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds, mysqlimport

i am running an Amazon RDS instance, which already contains the database schema. Using mysqldump and following this guide [1], i am able to remote import the dump, which contains INSERT statements.

The SQL file is only 4MB large and contains around 30.000 statements. Despite this small size,  the import takes 40 minutes to complete. Is it possible to speed this up? I am not sure if mysqlimport is valuable with such a small file. I tried to deactivate auto commit but no improvement was noticeable.

I already know, that i can not ssh to the instance or move the file to the local RDS filesystem.

Thank you,
Sebastian

[1] http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933

Comment: I think i have found a solution. Using multiple row INSERT, i can reduce the number of statements drastically what is way more performant.

Comment: put "--compress" on the mysqlimport line. I measured it. It will speed it up!

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump/import are very slow tools and they are eficient is very few cases. You could have a better speed if you script the import and execute the commands 1 by 1.

Comment: Executing the commands one after the other was the problem in the first place because the RTTs added up (i think). Sending 10 multi row inserts instead of 30.000 normal inserts solved my problem.